# Can't find this handwritten kanji/kana?

Tags: words, kanji, particles, writing-identification

I'm a beginner and this word or particle or whatever it is has left me dumbfounded. Greatly appreciate if anyone can tell me what this is supposed to be.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any other context for this character?  As suggested in the comment above, it looks like the hiragana character 「れ」.  However, depending on the context, it could possibly be a handwritten version of 「水」.  I have seen instances where 水 written quickly ended up looking like れ (or [check Google Images for 水 草書](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1283&bih=909&q=%E6%B0%B4%E3%80%80%E8%8D%89%E6%9B%B8&oq=%E6%B0%B4%E3%80%80%E8%8D%89%E6%9B%B8&gs_l=img.3..0i30k1.1746.6067.0.6561.13.12.0.0.0.0.145.1117.7j5.12.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..5.8.764...0j0i4k1j0i4i37k1j0i4i24k1j0i8i30k1.GkSWx7A5Wgs)).